# Cordova AWS JS returning items in different order

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently struggling with cordova and AWS. I am about to download multiple items. Currently it is working successfully, but the array I build up is filled in a random order. Is there anyway I can keep track of the file being downloaded?

```
function GetFilesFromAWS(filesToGet) {

        AWS.config.update();
        AWS.config.region = REGION

        var fileDown = [];
        var fileDwnCnt = 0;
        var filecnt = 0;
        var fileDownNames = [];
        var fileDownNameCnt = 0;
        for (var file in filesToGet) {
            if (filesToGet.length != 0) {
                if (filesToGet[file].indexOf('.') != -1) {
                    fileDownNames[fileDownNameCnt] = filesToGet[file];
                    var s3bucket = new AWS.S3();
                    s3bucket.getObject({ Bucket: BUCKET, Key: filesToGet[file] }, function (err, data) {
                        if (err)// an error occurred
                        {
                            console.log(err, err.stack);
                        }
                        else {// successful response
                            fileDown[fileDwnCnt] = data.Body.buffer; //convert the data to a buffer
                            fileDwnCnt++;
                            if (fileDwnCnt == filecnt - 1) {
                                SaveFile(fileDown, fileDownNames)
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    fileDownNameCnt++;
                    filecnt++;
                }
            } else {
                navigator.notification.alert("Documents Are up to date.");
            }

        }
```

And the code to saving files:

```
function SaveFile(fileDownloaded, fileName) {
            var files = fileDownloaded;
            var fileNames = fileName;
            fileCnt = 0;
            var fileNamesCnt = 0;
            var message = true;
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSys) {
                //The folder is created if doesn't exist
                fileSys.root.getDirectory("Documentation", { create: true }, function (directory) {
                    for (var file in files) {
                        directory.getFile(fileNames[file].substring(fileNames[file].lastIndexOf('/')), { create: true }, function (file) {
                            file.createWriter(function (writer) {
                                writer.onwrite = function (evt) {
                                    if (message) {
                                        navigator.notification.alert("All Documents are updated");
                                        message = false;
                                    }
                                };

                                writer.onwriteend = function (evt) {
                                };
                                writer.write(files[fileCnt]);
                                fileCnt++;
                            });

                        }, resolveOnError);
                    }
                }, resolveOnError);
            }, resolveOnError);
        }
```